# Random 6-8 alphanumerical TMP file generates while working with Office 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

So this problem has been on my cousin's desktop for quite a while. It seems that Microsoft Office 2010 creates random 6-8 alphanumerical .tmp files for some reason, e.g. 693B10.tmp, B54310FD.tmp.

The real problem is when my cousin deletes one of those files, an actual excel file also gets deleted. But when she searches for the file in the Recycle Bin, the excel file is not there, but the tmp file is there. Restoring the tmp file doesnt help bring back the excel file but this problem does bothers me.

Comment: Where do these .tmp files get generated? (What is the file path/directory?)

Comment: It's found in the save path of my documents. If I save it in desktop, it will appear there.

Comment: I assume when you say Microsoft Office makes these random .tmp files you mean one of the applications under the Microsoft Office Suite (ie Word).  These .tmp files are likely copies of the file at hand used for restorations.  Try saving then closing a file with File Explorer open, does the .tmp file automatically disappear? Is the "Show Hidden items" option enabled as well in File Explorer? If so, what happens if you disable hidden items?

Comment: I understand if the _~filename.tmp_ appears and disappears when opening the file, but this .tmp is not hidden at all. I got a copy of the files from my cousin and found out I can open the .tmp file with WinRar and [got these in the file.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i5alw.png)

I haven't gone through the files yet though, but it seems like the temporary file that the usual Microsoft makes for restoration.